# How can I get array of Sundays between two dates?

Tags: perl

I'm starting out with two dates.

```
my $date1 = 01/01/2016;
my $date2 = 05/15/2016;
```

I need to put all the dates of the Sundays between two dates.

Any idea where I should start?

Comment: [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime)

Comment: You should start by picking a module. I'm partial to [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime), using [DateTime::Format::Strptime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime::Format::Strptime) for the parsing.

Comment: Is that Sundays between *and including* both dates?

Comment: yes, between and including both dates

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Your solution is good](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41130369/14660), but it potentially consumes a lot of memory creating an array of Sundays that might never be used. DateTime objects are not small nor cheap.

An alternative is an iterator, a function which every time it's called generates the next Sunday. It generates each Sunday on demand rather than calculating them all beforehand. This saves memory and supports potentially infinite Sundays.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

sub sundays_iterator {
    my($start, $end) = @_;

    # Since we're going to modify it, copy it.
    $start = $start->clone;

    # Move to Sunday, if necessary.
    $start->add( days => 7 - $start->day_of_week );

    # Create an iterator using a closure.
    # This will remember the values of $start and $end as
    # they were when the function was returned.
    return sub {
        # Clone the date to return it without modifications.
        # We always start on a Sunday.
        my $date = $start->clone;

        # Move to the next Sunday.
        # Do this after cloning because we always start on Sunday.
        $start->add( days => 7 );

        # Return Sundays until we're past the end date
        return $date <= $endDate ? $date : ();
    };
}
```

That returns a closure, an anonymous subroutine which remembers the lexical variables it was created with. Sort of like an inside out object, a function with data attached. You can then call it like any subroutine reference.

```
my $sundays = sundays_iterator($startDate, $endDate);
while( my $sunday = $sundays->() ) {
    say $sunday;
}
```

The upside is it saves a lot of memory, this can be especially important if you're taking the dates as user input: a malicious attacker can ask you for an enormous range consuming a lot of your server's memory.

It also allows you to separate generating the list from using the list. Now you have a generic way of generating Sundays within a date range (or, with a slight tweak, any day of the week).

The downside is it's likely to be a bit slower than building an array in a loop... but probably not noticeably so. Function calls are relatively slow in Perl, so making one function call for each Sunday will be slower than looping, but calling those DateTime methods (which call other methods which call other methods) will swamp that cost. Compared to using DateTime, calling the iterator function is a drop in the bucket.

Comment: He could simply move `print "$sunday\n";` into the first loop if the memory was an issue. [Sorry, didn't know you were going to answer when I did my update.]

Comment: @ikegami That would weld generating the list of Sundays with using the list of Sundays. An iterator allows the list of Sundays (and with a small tweak any weekday) to be used for any purpose without having to pre-generate them.

Comment: Was the change from `print $sunday->strftime("%m/%d/%Y");` to `say $sunday;` intentional?

Comment: @ikegami I didn't make such a change, I guess you're referring to the OP's own answer. `say $sunday` is just to demonstrate the iterator works. They're DateTime objects now, they can be formatted however.

Comment: Your answer doesn't run on its own; it simply lists modifications to make to Bill's, including changing `print $sunday->strftime("%m/%d/%Y");` into `say $sunday->strftime("%m/%d/%Y");`. Call that what you want; it's not important. What I'm actually asking is if you have any objection to fixing that bug (e.g. by using `say $sunday->strftime("%m/%d/%Y");` to get the OP's format)?

Comment: @ikegami It's ok that it doesn't run on its own, it's not supposed to be a complete script but demonstrating how you can do it as a reusable function. The question doesn't ask about formatting, the OP seems to know what they're doing for parsing and formatting, and you covered it well; I saw no need to repeat it. It's just showing off the closure iterator technique. If you really want to make the change, ok, but I prefer your solution of setting the formatter on `$startDate` and inheriting it via `clone` rather than remembering to use `strftime` on every print.

Comment: Getting alternative patterns out there is a useful goal. Well done.

Answer (score 4):

You should start by picking a module. I'm partial to [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime), using [DateTime::Format::Strptime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime::Format::Strptime) for the parsing.

```
use DateTime                   qw( );
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );

my $start_date = "01/01/2016";
my $end_date   = "05/15/2016";

my $format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
  pattern   => '%m/%d/%Y',
  time_zone => 'floating',  # Best not to use "local" for dates with no times.
  on_error  => 'croak',
);

my $start_dt = $format->parse_datetime($start_date)->set_formatter($format);
my $end_dt   = $format->parse_datetime($end_date  )->set_formatter($format);

my $sunday_dt = $start_dt->clone->add( days => 7 - $start_dt->day_of_week );
while ($sunday_dt <= $end_dt) {
  print "$sunday_dt\n";
  $sunday_dt->add( days => 7 );
}
```

---

Note: You really shouldn't use `DateTime->new` as Bill used and Schwern endorsed. It's not the recommended use of DateTime because it creates code that's far more complicated and error-prone. As you can see, using a formatter cut the code size in half.

---

Note: Schwern is advocating the use of an iterator, replacing the last four lines of my answer with something 4 times longer (all the code in his answer). There's no reason for that high level complexity! He goes into length saying how much memory the iterator is saving, but it doesn't save any at all.

Answer (score 3):

DateTime::Set makes constructing an iterator easy:

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime ();
use DateTime::Set ();

my $start_date = "01/01/2016";
my $end_date   = "05/15/2016";

my $format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
  pattern   => '%m/%d/%Y',
  time_zone => 'local',
  on_error  => 'croak',
);

my $iterator = DateTime::Set->from_recurrence(
  start => $format->parse_datetime($start_date)->set_formatter($format),
  end => $format->parse_datetime($end_date)->set_formatter($format),
  recurrence => sub { $_[0]->add( days => 7 - $_[0]->day_of_week || 7 ) }, # next Sunday after $_[0]
);

while ( my $date = $iterator->next ) {
  say $date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with but please let me know if there is a better way.

```
use DateTime;

my $date1 = "1/1/2016";
my $date2 = "5/15/2016";

my ($startMonth, $startDay, $startYear) = split(/\//, $date1);
my ($endMonth, $endDay, $endYear) = split(/\//, $date2);

my $startDate = DateTime->new(
     year  => $startYear,
     month => $startMonth,
     day   => $startDay
);

my $endDate = DateTime->new(
     year  => $endYear,
     month => $endMonth,
     day   => $endDay
);

my @sundays;

do {
  my $date = DateTime->new(
     year  => $startDate->year,
     month => $startDate->month,
     day   => $startDate->day
  );

  push @sundays, $date if ($date->day_of_week == 7);
  $startDate->add(days => 1);

} while ($startDate <= $endDate);

foreach my $sunday (@sundays) {
  print $sunday->strftime("%m/%d/%Y");
}
```

Comment: Since days of the week are contiguous (unless we're getting into Julian vs Gregorian calendar gaps) you can speed that up by 7 (or maybe 6) by first moving `$startDate` to a Sunday once using `$startDate->day_of_week` and then adding 7 days to get the next Sunday until you pass the `$endDate`. It also might be a hair faster to `my $date = $startDate->clone`. And, finally, Time::Piece might work faster than DateTime since it comes with a lot less baggage.

Comment: @ikegami While your revisions are very good, they fundamentally alter someone else's answer. Put them up as your own answer or comments instead.

Comment: I disagree. Problems with the answer should be fixed in the answer. A clone shouldn't be made. Now there's three answers that all say 'use DateTime".

Comment: @ikegami It's ok for an answer to be wrong. Problems with an answer are solved with downvotes and comments, they're opinion, particularly poignant because the code in the answer works fine. Moderator edit *privilege* is for smaller fixes about formatting, not wholesale changing the content. If a mod edits the code, nobody else has a say, and the explanation is hidden in history. And it's Just Fine to have multiple answers showing multiple different ways to do it; even if they use the same library you see the techniques are rather different. That's StackOverflow Working As Designed™.